# Can I exchange ACLs between Servers?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get the ACL of a path on Server A, store it in a Variable and set the exact same ACL on Server B?

```
$session = New-PSSession $remoteIIS -Credential $AdminCred2 -Authentication Negotiate -Port 5985
$acl = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $sourceACL,$Name {
    param($sourceACL,$Name)
    $sACL = Get-Acl -Path ($sourceACL.Get_Item($Name))
    return $sACL
}
$rmps = Remove-PSSession $session
$setacl = set-acl -Path $spp -AclObject $acl -ErrorAction Stop
```

this is my code which should set the input ACL on my path, but it doesn't deploy users like IUSR which have read/write access on the source acl. it doesn't deploy them at all.

how can I exchange ACL Data between Servers?

Comment: Depends on whether the ACL contains entries for computer-specific security principals, or only builtin principals. Are these servers domain members or workgroup/standalone?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 4 IIS Servers inside the DMZ in a workgroup/standalone

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. IUSR, IISAPPPOOL virtual accounts etc. are all local to the machine's Security Account Manager database. They don't exist across multiple servers. What you could do is loop through the entries in the ACL on one server, and then recreate the corresponding entries on the other machine based on names

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i was hoping i won't have to do that :-). damn. i'll try, thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can use [this](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/compare_acls.shtml) as a starting point. You'll need to canonicalize the identity references, though.